# Django: use first name instead of username in login success message

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am using the following view to display a welcome back message when users login successfully. I want to use first name instead of the username attribute in the message, I tried to implement methods such as `request.user.get_short_name()`, but somehow I could not get it right. Is there a short way for this or I have to define a method inside the class?

```
class LoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
    success_message = 'Welcome back %(username)s!'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
class LoginView(SuccessMessageMixin, FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return 'Welcome back {}!'.format(self.request.user.first_name)
```